# Does Safari fire a message when an extension is installed?

Tags: safari-extension

I'm setting up a web page where the user can install our extension from. I'd like to say "congratulations" when the user manages to install it.

I'm not able to find anything to listen to to detect this. Does Safari fires any message when an extension is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something like this before by just putting the code in the global page, and using a hidden settings item to ensure it is only run the first time:

```
if (!safari.extension.settings.hasRun) {
    safari.extension.settings.hasRun = true;
    alert('Congratulations!');
}
```

One thing to be aware of is that any injected scripts are only injected on newly loaded pages, or after a refresh. So it's a bit trickier to use the above code to dispatch a message to an injected script to modify the contents of the currently open page. You will either have to force a refresh, or alternatively just open a tab with a welcome message:

```
if (!safari.extension.settings.hasRun) {
    safari.extension.settings.hasRun = true;
    safari.application.openBrowserWindow();
    safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url  = "http://www.example.com/welcome";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, easy and clever :) I wonder if in some way it is possible to message the page from the global page so to avoid refresh. I'm trying to post a message to the page with safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.page.dispatchMessage it looks like it is sent but I'm not able to listen to it from my page's js (tried window.addEventListener and document.addEventListener but it looks like it doesn't work).

Comment: As far as I know, the js actually on the page is kept completely separate from extensions for security reasons. I can't think of any way to inject additional js onto a page that was loaded before your extension was installed. You could consider temporarily adding in a toolbar button and programmatically activating a popover page from that, which can contain your message, but that's not so different from forcing a refresh or opening a new tab.